# Graph printing on top of eachother - networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

```
T10,T11,T12,T13 = nx.random_tree(10),nx.random_tree(11),nx.random_tree(12),nx.random_tree(13)
setTTrees = [T10,T11,T12,T13]
print("1.")
nx.draw(T10, **opts)
code10 = pruefer_code(T10)
print("The Prufer code is", code10)
T102 = tree_pruefer(code10)
nx.draw(T102, **opts)
```

The two graphs (which end up being the same) print on top of eachother, any way of separating them and drawing on a different line? Any help appreciated :)

Output below:

1.
The Prufer code is [0, 4, 4, 6, 4, 1, 8, 6]

[image: graphs]